# Walletconnect support for cashapp

Tags: walletconnect

\Is WalletConnect compatible with Cash App wallets, allowing users to link their Cash App accounts and access its features seamlessly, just like they can with other wallets listed on the WalletConnect website? I'm curious to know if WalletConnect extends its support to Cash App, which has gained significant popularity as a digital payment platform. Being able to connect Cash App wallets through WalletConnect would enable users to leverage the convenience and security of WalletConnect's decentralized protocol while managing their funds and engaging in transactions on the Cash App platform.

Comment: WalletConnect is an open protocol: it is up to individual applications to support it, not WalletConnect to support applications. As this question about the roadmap of a third party closed source product, it does not belong to this website, but to the customer support of the named product.